# Matcher doesn't contain all matched groups

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a RegEx that will match a pattern as follows:

- `@Mike Hello Mike, how are you doing today?`
- `Hello, I'm Mike.`

My RegEx looks as follows: `^(?:@(\w|-|_|)*)?\s*(.*)$`

However in my Code the `Matcher` somehow only recognizes `Hello Mike ......`. `@Mike` isn't recognized.

**Code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String withAt = "@Mike Hello Mike, how are you doing today?";
    String withoutAt = "Hello, I'm Mike.";

    matchString(withAt);
    matchString(withoutAt);
} 

private static void matchString(String messageString) {
    System.out.println("Maching String: " + messageString);
    
    Pattern messagePattern = Pattern.compile( "^(?:@(\\w|-|_|)*)?\\s*(.*)$" );
    Matcher matcher = messagePattern.matcher(messageString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("@: " +  matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Message: " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Running this peace of code will result in the following output:

```
Maching String: @Mike Hello Mike, how are you doing today?
@:                
Message: Hello Mike, how are you doing today?


Maching String: Hello, I'm Mike.
@: null
Message: Hello, I'm Mike.
```

**Question:**

Why does the `withAt`-String not print an `@: Mike` to the console? Where is this peace of information?

Comment: Try: `^(?:@([\\w-]+))?\\s*(.*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not capture `@Mike`. Use

```java
Pattern.compile( "^(?:@([\\w-]*))?\\s*(.*)$" )
```

See the [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/YnC6dM/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\w-]*                   any character of: word characters (a-
                               z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '-' (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```